# Why do registration.php and app/etc/config.php coexist in Magento2?

Tags: php, magento2

In Magento2 they have introduced

> app/etc/config.php

which looks like this a bit.

```
<?php
return array (
  'modules' => 
  array (
    'Magento_Store' => 1,
    'Magento_Contacts' => 1,
    'Namespace_Modulename' => 1
  ),
);
```

in which all modules reside. We can enable or disable the module using 1/0 over there. It also tells Magento which module it should go through in each request. If Magento already knows which module it should go through and which not then what's the purpose of having the `registration.php` file inside `app/code/namespace/modulename`?

Answer (score -1):

Registration.php introduce module name to magento 2.

We can enable or disable module by config.php (app/etc/config.php) in magento 2.